# Flutter: How do i stop rendering "Widget build()" unnecessarily again and again?

Tags: dart, flutter

This is a small POC in Flutter, where my **build()** function is being called again and again.

This was not expected at all without any loops and after a lot of research, I am calling **"Future" in initState()** as well.

But **still** facing the **same issue**.

*Thank you in advance* for time!

> What have I tried..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//http_request
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http; //to handle the http request
// import 'dart:async'; // for async functions
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'dart:convert'; //to convert the http response in JSON formate

import 'HomePage.dart';

    class Reports extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _Reports createState() => _Reports();
    }

    class _Reports extends State<Reports> {
  static String url = "Some Url";
  String _response = "abc";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTradeName_dropdown_ITR_Computation_DATA();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print('body');

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: new Text(_response),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future getTradeName_dropdown_ITR_Computation_DATA() async {
    try {
      http.Response response =
              await http.get("http://" + url );
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {

          String jsonTradeName_dropdown = response.body;
          _response = jsonTradeName_dropdown;
        });
      }
    } on Exception {
      setState(() {
        _response = "Some error occored. Please Try again...";
      });
    }
  }
}
```

> output:

```
I/flutter ( 5760): body
I/flutter ( 5760): body
I/flutter ( 5760): body
I/flutter ( 5760): body
I/flutter ( 5760): body
I/flutter ( 5760): body
I/flutter ( 5760): body
I/flutter ( 5760): body
I/flutter ( 5760): body
I/flutter ( 5760): body
I/flutter ( 5760): body
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you actually use this widget ?? Thx

Comment: That is not an issue.

Comment: yes @ Ferdi, the full code is updated where i have actually used this widget.

Comment: @pskink I am initiating http.get() in initState(), outside build.

Comment: It seems that build is called for each frame render, even if the frame did not change and every time you call `setState` so it seems to be a normal behavior : https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/#5-build

Comment: @Maxouille That could be a normal behaviour but I had placed DataTable in build(). Since it is rendering, again and again, my DataTable is getting lagged horribly.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use a FutureBuilder. I'm new to flutter so I don't know if it will solve your problem.

Comment: I request everyone to flag this question as a serious problem so it can be reviewed by the moderator as well. because I have gone through many similar posts where everyone is struggling with this problem

Comment: @bunny Can you mention the post where you have seen this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You were making couple of mistakes, here is the correct code. You should use a `String` instead of a `Text` widget to show the response.

```
class _Reports extends State<Reports> {
  static String url = "url";
  String _response = "abc";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTradeName_dropdown_ITR_Computation_DATA();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print('body');

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: new Text(_response),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future getTradeName_dropdown_ITR_Computation_DATA() async {
    try {
      http.Response response =
      await http.get("url_goes_here");

      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
          String jsonTradeName_dropdown = response.body;
          _response = jsonTradeName_dropdown;
        });
      }
    } on Exception {
      setState(() {
        _response = "Some error occored. Please Try again...";
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for those changes... I have made a note of it. But This is still not solving my core issue. Widget build() is still iterating again and again. "body" is being printed again and again. Getting same output and no changes yet.

Comment: The code looks OK to me then, I am not sure how you are using it in parent class.

Comment: This is the only class. @CopsOnRoad

Comment: Can you tell me the `url` then? I will try to fetch it on my own.

Comment: OK, I deleted it.

Comment: Thank You. And even delete String url on 2nd line. Thanks again in prior.

Answer (score 1):

The proper model for understanding build() is that you should imagine it is being called sixty times a second.  So your build() routine should be fast and idempotent.

In practice, there are optimizations made by the framework so that it isn't called except when needed, but you shouldn't view excessive calls to build() as a failure.